# why is assigned java variable behaving like a reference?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Hi i dont know if this question has already been asked before but this is getting really annoying...

Ok so i have a class called Test:

```
public class Test {
    public static Test testObject = new Test(5);//Creates a test object with an initialized value of 5;
    int number;
    public Test(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And of course my main class...

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test anotherObject = Test.testObject;//this is not a reference right?
        System.out.println(Test.testObject.number);//This prints 5
        anotherObject.number = 50;// changing anotherObject's number. NOT testObject's Number.
        System.out.println(Test.testObject.number);//if that was true this whould of still been 5, but it prints 50!!?? why does testObject's number even change if im not even changing that value?
    }
}
```

if there is something im doing wrong please let me know, thank you very much!!

Comment: `Test anotherObject = Test.testObject;//this is not a reference right?` yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program you have a SINGLE instance of `Test`, you just name it differently every time.

```
Test anotherNumber = Test.testObject;
```

Does **NOT** create a new object. It only reference to the same object, you say "Whenever I write `anotherNumber`, I actually meant to write `Test.testObject`".

So, when you later change `anotherNumber.number = 50;`, you do: `Test.testObject.number = 50;`, and thus when you print `Test.testObject`, you see 50.

---

Edit:

If you want to be able to create copy of some object, you can introduce a copy constructor:

```
public Test(Test original) { 
   this.number = original.number;
}
```

And use it with `someOtherNumber = new Test(Test.testObject);`

Comment: Thankks for your help!, this really helped!, +1

Comment: EDIT: So how would i make anotherObject/anotherNumber, be just a new object but with testObject's characteristics

Comment: @BryanGriffin You should use the constructor for this `Test someOtherNumber = new Test(5);` to make it with `number == 5`. You could also introduce a new copy constructor `public Test(Test original) { this.number = original.number; }`, and use it with `someOtherNumber = new Test(Test.testObject);`

Comment: I know this is a possible solution: `Test anotherNumber = new Test(Test.testObject.number); `but is there other solution??

Answer (score 0):

When in your class Test, you are creating a new Object of Test that is always 5. So take out the Test object that you created in the Test class, then use the following code in your main method:

```
Test anotherNumber = new Test(5);
System.out.println(anotherNumber.number);
anotherNumber.number = 50;
System.out.println(anotherNumber.number);
```